# Подключение к удаленной БД без MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

В моем учебном заведении нет MySql, а лишь стандартные библиотеки. Каким образом можно подключиться к удаленной БД на хосте, используя стандартные библиотеки?

Comment: *каким образом можно подключиться к удаленной БД* Точно так же, как и к локальной. Только указать адрес удалённого хоста в настройках соединения, убедиться в существовании неспецифического пользователя (`host='%'`), и молиться, чтобы файрволы пропускали трафик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя подключиться к MySQL совсем без ничего. Как минимум, вам нужно сделать что-то из этого:

- Подключить к своему проекту библиотеку [MySQL Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) и работать с ее классами из [MySql.Data.MySqlClient](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html)
- Установить на все целевые машины [ODBC-драйвер MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) и работать в программе со стандартными классами из [System.Data.Odbc](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc?view=netcore-2.2)

Comment: Вопрос по какому протоколу подключается какое-либо приложение к БД MySQL?)

Comment: @SonicMyst по протоколу MySQL :) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/client-server-protocol.html Указанное в ответе ПО реализует именно его.

Comment: ну строго говоря не имею ничего(я про те самые библиотеки которые используются для подключения и общения с MYSQL) подключиться можно, но весьма муторно, пришлось бы писать запросы ручками, так что условно да, не имея те самых библиотек не подключишься)